# remove html codes when posting URL in the wall

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-checkins

When I paste a URL on the Facebook wall, it displays the image and also gets the description from the URL. But in my case the description comes with html codes, how to just display the description.

My url is www.maniacstore.com/test.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try scraping your URL using the debug too: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maniacstore.com%2Ftest.html

If you are using PHP, you can remove HTML from your code using the `strip_tags();` function. I don't actually see any HTML in your page so maybe scraping the URL using the link above will fix the issue.

Comment: http://www.maniacstore.com/Dior-Hypnotic-Poison-EDT-100ml.html tried with this URL also, but no luck